# I have issue with listview,which I used to store DB contents

Tags: java, android, android-listview

In my application used simple listview which used to display the string contents from DB.

I have button called next if I click on the next item will highlighted by some color,it's working but problem is if the items are more than 7 items it's and on click 'Next' button giving forceclose .What is the problem.Please give me idea to solve it.

EDIT:

I used simple listview to display items on it,is this is because of listview reaches end(bottom)of listview or some other problem?Can you tel me what is wrong with it what i had come across this issue?

My code is for 'Next' button:

```
else if(v.getId()==R.id.buttonBookmarkrNext)
    {
        if((pos+1) == length)
        {   
            //if no of files exist in a arraylist and current position of a file matches do the following
            pos = 0;
            audiofile=(String) lv.getItemAtPosition(pos);
            Toast.makeText(this, " next file1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            lv.getChildAt(length-1).setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
            lv.getChildAt(pos).setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        }
        else if(pos<length)
        {
            //if no of files exist in a arraylist(lenght) are greater than current position(pos) of a file  do the following
            pos ++;
            //audioDetails = (ArrayList<String[]>) lv.getItemAtPosition(pos);
            audiofile=(String) lv.getItemAtPosition(pos);
            Toast.makeText(this, " next file",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            lv.getChildAt(pos-1).setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
            lv.getChildAt(pos).setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            String str=(String) lv.getItemAtPosition(pos);
            //Log.e("next file end",str);
            Toast.makeText(this, " end file"+str,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is your Next button located ?In side list item ?

Comment: No,it's out side the listview.

Comment: What do you see in logcat when it force closes?

Comment: When it force closes, which branch of the if statement does it take? Is that the first time that branch is taken?

Comment: It gives null pointer exception for  else if(pos<length)
        {      lv.getChildAt(pos).setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
points to this line .

Comment: @VilasmatiHanjagi and is that not enough information for you to solve the issue? Remember that pos is 0 based, and that means when `pos == length - 1`, doing `pos++` will make pos point past the end of the array.

Comment: I would advise you to read on how the `getChildAt` method works for the `ListView` widget.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here...

```
else if(pos<length)    // pos should be less than length-1, 
        {

            pos ++;

        .......
        .......

        }
```

**Try this way...**

```
else if(pos<(length-1))     
        {

            pos ++;

        .......
        .......

        }
```

Comment: Actually my code is working as per need but the thing is that next button works only for 7 items in listview.After that for 8th item on click 'next' button gives forceclose saying null pointer exception even though elements present in listview.

Comment: I used simple listview to display items on it,is this is because of listview reaches end(bottom)of listview or some other problem?Can you tel me what is wrong with it what i had come across this issue?@Kumar Vivek Mitra